# Como abrir o VS Code dentro de uma pasta específica pelo terminal do Macbook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, osx

Estou fazendo um curso de React onde o instrutor depois de instalar e configurar o webpack dentro de uma pasta específica (no meu caso dentro de uma pasta criada chamada products, criada dentro de outra pasta chamada ecomm...) pede para abrirmos o VS Code pelo terminal.

Digitei o mesmo comando que ele passou na aula, mas só dá erro... segue print da tela...Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não precisa ser com linha de comando, você pode abrir o VS Code normalmente, ir em Arquivo > Abrir pasta

Answer (score 2):

Conforme o [manual do VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac):

- Abra a paleta de comando (Cmd+Shift+P) e digite 'shell command' para encontrar a instalação da ferramenta de linha de comando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Instale a ferramenta e reinicie o terminal

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou reinstalar o vscode?

congere este link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955500/code-not-working-in-command-line-for-visual-studio-code-on-osx-mac

Neste link acima manda - > Update: use Uninstall 'code' command in PATH** rodar esse comando dentro do vs code
e depois
Install 'code' command in PATH** command

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que não seja tão diferente dos linux e windows:

No Windows, você pode navegar até a pasta e dentro da pasta você digita o comando "code ." sem as aspas (windows).
No linux, dependendo do aplicativo instalado, dentro da pasta no terminal você digita "codium ." (Parrot OS, Debian).

Pode tambem passar uma subpasta pelo comando como por exemplo code ./src

Provavelmente você ja fez pesquisas relacionadas, mas aqui vai um link com informações úteis para usar o vscode no mac.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

Comment: O problema é que o comando `code` não está no PATH, conforme apontado na mensagem de erro: *command not found: code*

Answer (score -3):

Eu faço desta forma aqui

Abrindo uma pasta no VS Code pelo terminal.
start code /c/bryan/workspace

esta e a forma que eu utilizo.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).